# Regex to exclude specific websites in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which matches all the websites but i want to exclude 2 specific websites from this regex?

Regex is

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Websites I want to exclude are

```
www.gfycat.com
www.imgur.com
imgur.com/*
gfycat.com/*
```

Is it possible to write the regex which exludes the specific websites? Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

```
/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/
```

I have attached the screenshot for match patterns.
[image]

Using RES and regex need to be implemented here.[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the end? Replace the text with some other text? Or just collect matches? The technique will be the same: match what you do not need and then match and capture what you need. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7F3wQU/1). The captured text is what you need to allow, else, do not.  Have you got the access to the code?

Comment: How are you using this regex? Are you searching for urls or are you validating them? Can I use a start-of-string anchor `^` in the regex?

Comment: Iam using it in Reddit to filter out posts and hide all other posts except `gfycat.com and imgur.com` posts by matching the regex.If i use the above mentioned regex `all the posts` are hidden.

Comment: Stuffing all your application logic in a single regular expression tends to be really hard to write and maintain (though many people do it, I admit that). Is it really necessary? I mean, are you using a tool (e.g. a third-party plug-in) that expects a single regexp and doesn't allow custom code?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/EwKAbR/2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It helped Thanks.Mention the Logic in answer as well

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `i.imgur.com` is failing any generalized solution for *.imgur.com/*

Comment: @BackdoorCipher: There is no universal solution for this with a plain single regex. You might try enhancing to [this one](https://regex101.com/r/EwKAbR/4), but there still may be other edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/tN3Wgl/4)

```
^(?:(?!(?:www\.)?(?:google|gfycat|imgur))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256})\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Comment: `www.gfycat.com/ABC` Fails

Comment: @BackdoorCipher Some spelling mistake in pattern. Now you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why you need regex to do the same. Can you not do something simple like the below, unless I understood it completely wrong.

```
url = new URL('https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=bN5IWaP7CYyDtAHKv4CIBg#q=hello');

if url.hostname == 'www.google.com'
// ignore
else
// process
```

**The answer is not relevant to the specific question as OP is using a different tool**

Comment: I have an extenstion which have filter module and I will attach the Screenshot here.